# Jsp file upload error

Tags: mysql, jsp

My input type is

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="sid" required>
```

I get the value using

```
String img=request.getParameter("sid");
```

I store it using

```
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
    String sapid=request.getParameter("sapid");
    String email=request.getParameter("email");
    String ph=request.getParameter("pn");
    String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
    String img=request.getParameter("sid");
    String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
    File imgfile = new File(img);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = formatter.parse(dob);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

    ps = c.prepareStatement("insert into personal_details values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setLong(1,Long.parseLong(sapid));
    ps.setString(2,name);
    ps.setString(3,lname);
    ps.setString(4,email);
    ps.setLong(5,Long.parseLong(ph));
    ps.setString(6,gender);
    ps.setDate(7,sqlDate);
    ps.setBinaryStream(8,fin,(int)imgfile.length());
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

But when I execute it I gives me an error

```
java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing
[/registerstudent.jsp] at line [40]

37:         String img=request.getParameter("sid"); 
38:         String dob=request.getParameter("dob"); 
39:         File imgfile = new File(img); 
40:         FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile); 
41:         SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 42:         Date date = formatter.parse(dob); 
43:         java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); java.io.FileNotFoundException:
Capture3.PNG (The system cannot find the file specified)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)

org.apache.jsp.registerstudent_jsp._jspService(registerstudent_jsp.java:155)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I choose a file and click on the submit button. But on clicking the browser displays the above mentioned message. The browser cannot find the file specified

Comment: Have you verified (in line 39) that img has a value, and that the value is the correct value? Kudos for putting the line numbers in the code.

Comment: How can I verify that the value is a correct value

Comment: You can add a statement after that line to echo the value of ```img``` to the browser.

Comment: I echoed the value of img. The result is the name of the file that I uploaded

Comment: Is the filename in ```img``` just the filename, or the full path to the filename? Also, typically, the actual file saved after the upload will not match the original filename. It will be made unique by adding the date/time to the filename.

Comment: its only the file name

Comment: It will need to be the full path and filename of the uploaded file at line 39.

Comment: how do I get it then?

Comment: Check out $_FILES. Also, make sure your form is multi-part.

Comment: my form is multipart

Comment: $_FILES is for php I guess

Comment: SMH! Sorry about that cheif!